# Is it possible to list all tags?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

Choosing a tag can be a problem for me, because it is hard to find suitable existing ones.. 
Is there some way to list all tags, without having to page through 30 pages... 
I would like a nice simple list which I can copy-paste into my text editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why you want this, but... [Click here](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/81002/all-tags-by-frequency?opt.textResults=true) - they're ordered with the most-used ones on top.

Comment: Thanks, that's ideal... It's much easier to get a general overview,  by viewing them all on a single page, space seperated, or columns, etc

Comment: I'd like to see this too, however the provided link no longer works.

Comment: @dubiousjim: fixed.